# How to return an array with jest-fetch-mock?

Tags: jest-fetch-mock

I need to mock an fetch call which returns an array with Jest Fetch Mock:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/

```
it ('<Main />', () => {
  const wrapper = render (<Main />);

  fetch.mockResponseOnce (
    JSON.stringify ([
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'hi',
      },
    ])
  );

  wrapper.debug ();
});
```

However I'm getting an error:

```
(node:4667) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at undefined reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```